# Complex linear functionals and real linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> **Proposition:** Let $X$ be a vector space on $\mathbb{C}$. If $f$ is a complex linear functional on $X$ and $u=\text{Re} f$, then $u$ is a
>   real linear functional and $f(x) = u(x) - i u(ix)$ for all $ x \in X$.

I am using Folland, and the proof he gives of this is very brief:

> "If $f$ is complex linear and $u=\text{Re} f$, $u$ is clearly real
>   linear and $\text{Im} f(x) = - \text{Re}[if(x)] = -u(ix)$"

I am not very good with complex numbers, and only just started functional analysis this week. Where does folland get that $\text{Im} f(x) = - \text{Re}[if(x)] = -u(ix)$? I.e. why is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z \in \def\C{\mathbf C}\C$ be any complex number, then $\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}$
$$ z = \Re z + i\Im z $$
multiplying by $i$, we have
$$ iz = -\Im z + i\Re z$$
that is the real part of $iz$ is $\Re(iz) = -\Im z$, so we get 
$$ \Im z = -\Re (iz) $$
Folland applies this to $z = f(x)$, giving 
$$ \Im f(x) = -\Re [if(x)] $$
As $f$ is complex linear, $if(x) = f(ix)$, giving 
$$ \Im f(x) = -\Re f(ix) $$
As $u$ was defined to be $\Re f$, we have 
$$ \Im f(x) = -u(ix) $$
Hence
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \Re f(x) + i\Im f(x)\\
       &= u(x) + i \cdot \bigl(-u(ix)\bigr)\\
       &= u(x) -iu(ix) 
\end{align*}